# Subsets which overlap in one element

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinatorial-geometry

consider the set $\{1,...,n\}$, we want to decompose it into sets $S_1,....,S_t$ such that $\vert S_i\vert \geq  k$ for all i and $\vert S_i \cap S_j \vert \leq 1$ for all $i\neq j$.

Is there an upper bound on $t$? Obviously depending on n and k.

Clearly for $k=1$ we get no bound. And for $k=n$ we have $t=1$.

This problem comes from Lemma 2.1 in ["On the lattice property of the plane and some problems of Dirac, Motzkin and Erdős in combinatorial geometry"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02579184) by Jozsef Beck, 1983. There for $\sqrt{2n}<k \leq n$ it is claimed that $t < \frac{2n}{k}$, but I dont see it. The proof seems to use that $t \leq \frac{2n}{k}$ holds, if I assume that this is correct I can follow that claim.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
My idee is to show that $2n \geq \sum_{i=1}^t \vert S_i\vert \geq t \cdot k$. The right inequality is clear, but I miss an argument for the left one.

Comment: It is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3030747) that $t < \frac{n(n-1)}{k(k-1)}$, but this is not enough to prove $t<2n/k$ in the range $\sqrt{2n}<k<n$.

Comment: That is part i) of the lemma, the part I'm stuck in is ii).

Comment: I edited back in the link; turns out it works just fine, it was just a problem on my end. The paper gives a proof of $t<2n/k$ in their proof of lemma 2.1, is there are a particular step of their proof that confused you? I'd rather not write out the whole proof if you are just stuck on one step.

Comment: I'm stuck, where they assume that $t=\lceil 2n/k \rceil$. I mean sure if you assume that you get a contradiction, but why is it enough to show that this does not hold? What is with the case that $t > 2n/k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prove $t=\lceil 2n/k\rceil$ is impossible, that automatically implies $t$ is impossible whenever $t > \lceil 2n/k\rceil$. This is because if there existed $S_1,\dots,S_t$ satisfying the constaints, then you could just ignore some of the sets to get $S_1,\dots,S_{\lceil 2n/k\rceil}$ satisfying the constraints, so the latter being impossible implies the former is as well.